# c# Find and Replace Text in a Word Document

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, docx, novacode-docx

i want to Create and Manipulate Word Documents Programmatically Using DocX ! and create a word template `InvoiceTemplate.docx` this is my code :

```
protected void CreateDoc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Createa docx File
    DocX gDocument;
    gDocument = 
        DocX.Load(@Server.MapPath("InvoiceTemplate.docx"));
    gDocument = 
        CreateInvoiceFromTemplate(DocX.Load(@Server.MapPath("InvoiceTemplate.docx")));
    gDocument.SaveAs(@Server.MapPath("~/DocX/NewLoadedShipment.docx"));
}

private static DocX CreateInvoiceFromTemplate(DocX template)
{
    template.AddCustomProperty(
        new CustomProperty("{rechnung}", "5"));
    template.AddCustomProperty(
        new CustomProperty("{name}", "Maziar"));
    template.AddCustomProperty(
        new CustomProperty("{date}", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")));
    template.AddCustomProperty(
        new CustomProperty("{address}", "12345hamburg"));
    template.AddCustomProperty(
        new CustomProperty("{tell}", "2234543"));
    template.AddCustomProperty(
        new CustomProperty("{amount}", "1000"));
    template.AddCustomProperty(
        new CustomProperty("{rest}", "500"));
    template.AddCustomProperty(
        new CustomProperty("{tax}", "100"));
    template.AddCustomProperty(
        new CustomProperty("{total}", "600"));
    return template;
}
```

but nothing happend to my `NewLoadedShipment.docx` ! can some one help please !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I usually advocate Using DocXTemplateEngine for this purpose.  Simpler than using novacode-docx for template replacement.

Fills in standard mail merge fields in a simple way

```
var templateEngine = new swxben.docxtemplateengine.DocXTemplateEngine();
templateEngine.Process(
    source = "template.docx",
    destination = "dest.docx",
    data = new {
       Name = "SWXBEN"
    }
);
```

Available https://www.nuget.org/packages/swxben.docxtemplateengine/

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called "ReplaceText" in DocX that allows you to replace text within the document.

You must first reference you template like this for example...

```
DocX letter = DocX.Load(%YOUR TEMPLATE NAME%);
```

Then you can do...

```
letter.ReplaceText("%REPLACE_THIS%","%WITH_THIS%");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How can we replace only first occurrence using DocX > ReplaceText() method.
If anything else then help. It's Urgent. Thank you in Advance